# Openlayer3 3.9 vector layer ignores some linestrings

Tags: geojson, openlayers, line

I updated my small OL3 project to 3.9 but noticed that one of my vectorlayers now only displays very few features: [image: only one line displayed, but there should be connections between all nodes]

Other point layers work fine. Also I checked the basics:

- Browser calls and transfers geoJSON successfully
- [my geoJSON](http://paste.plattform32.de/view/a3348087) is valid and get displayed at [geojsonlint.com](http://geojsonlint.com/#sample-geojson-content) (using leaflet)
- firebug doesn't fires errors, even with ol-debug

As said it worked fine with OL3.5 but I needed to add the GeoJSON format to migrate. Works fine for point layers :/
Here is my code snippet:

```
    ...
    ,
    new ol.layer.Vector({
        title: 'Links',
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: '/api/links',
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
                //defaultDataProjection :'EPSG:4326', 
                projection: 'EPSG:3857'
            })
        }),
        style: [new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: 'yellow',
              width: 5
            })
          })],
          visible:true
    }),
    ...
```

Has anybody ideas how to isolate the problem? I guess I didn't found an OL bug, did I?

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample of you GeoJSON data.

Comment: Plz. click "my geoJSON" ;-)

Comment: Not related to your issue, but ol.format.GeoJSON does not have `projection` option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your feature objects all seem to have the same `id` member. The [GeoJSON specification](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-objects) states that:

> If a feature has a commonly used identifier, that identifier should be included as a member of the feature object with the name "id".

OpenLayers expects all features to have unique id's. All features with the same ID are considered to be the same feature.

You should make the ID property unique, or remove it.

Comment: d'ouh! You are right, this was the issue as my JSON serializer just fallback to the object classes itself. Suprisingly this worked for OL <= 3.5 but hey thats ok. Thanks for your time!